# OSB proxy service loosing jms messages from jms queue

Tags: jms, weblogic11g, osb

We have defined a proxy service to consume messages from a jms queue hosted in OSB weblogic. The OSB version is 11.1.1.6. This jms queue is fed by a jms bridge hosted in the same OSB weblogic whereas the source destination hosted in a foreigh weblogic environment.

We observed that close to 10% of the messages are not getting delivered from the jms queue to the proxy service. From the jms queue message logs, we observed that all the messages have received by the queue, although some messages have been lost during the transit from the jms queue to the OSB proxy. This is an intermittent issue. Any thought on this is much appreciated?

Comment: Are you using a durable subscription? Could you post your JMS config in your proxy service? It's possible that these messages where moved to an error queue or that you haven't configured your proxy that every message HAS to be delivered or put back in the JMS queue or error queue.